# Not able to mount external Windows hard drive partition

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

I am trying to mount a windows hard drive under Ubuntu. Know my Problem is that if I'm trying to mount it with different commands I always get the massage that the partition is not found.

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o ro /dev/sdb1 /media/WIN

mount: /media/ric/WIN_PART: Spezialgerät /dev/sdb1 not found.
```

other try

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/WIN

ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sdb1': File or directory not found

ntfs-3g 2017.3.23AR.3 integrated FUSE 28 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
        Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
          umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
          Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
```

I only find the partition with **sudo fdisk -l**

```
Festplatte /dev/sdb: 1,82 TiB, 2000398934016 Bytes, 3907029168 Sektoren
Festplattenmodell: 001-1CM164      
Einheiten: Sektoren von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorgröße (logisch/physikalisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
E/A-Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Festplattenbezeichnungstyp: dos
Festplattenbezeichner: 0xe6ba03e5

Gerät      Boot Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Kn Typ
/dev/sdb1            1 4294967295 4294967295    2T ee GPT
```

With **lsblk** I only find the disk

```
sdb           8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk
```

Other information that could by interesting.
To note is that the hard drive is from a raid system. And I am using the hard drive where I can find the partition (on the other one I can only find the disk). Also to note is that if I am trying to boot from the hard drive I am getting the problem “Your PC Ran into a Problem and Needs to Restart” loop, so I’m trying to save my data before I reset my pc.

1)Ubuntu 21.10

2)Lenovo_Raid, RAID0 (Stripe), 3.6TB

3)I have both

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb1

fsck von util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
File or directory not found when trying to open /dev/sdb1
Could the device not be there?
```

Comment: If this is one part of a RAID set, that radically changes the amount of work that needs to go into offering a solution. That bit really should be near the start of the question, not the end. That said, additional details will be needed. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re using (1) the type of RAID the disk is from (0/1/5/JBOD/etc.) (2) whether you have the other disks for the RAID set or not. With these details, it *might* be possible to offer solutions 

Comment: Have you tried running fsck against /dev/sdb1? sudo fsck /dev/sdb1 This should give a little extra info why it can't be mounted